# (GCP) How to save a specific instance when auto scaling in an instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform

After registering the instance group (Auto scaling instance min 1, max 5) and setting the external IP, the added instance remains and the instance with the external IP setting is deleted.

How to use external IP instance group?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a managed instance group, depending on the Load you selected for it to scale up, until this load is reached it will start to scale up. If there is no load, since you mention that the min is 1, even if you manually create new instances they will be down scaled since there is no Load.

For this, I would recommend creating an external [GCP LoadBalancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-l7-internal#configuring_with_a_vm-based_service) and get it to point to the managed instance group.
This way you can always reach these instances with a single external IP